# WPF Datagrid template removes ability to resize columns

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, resize

How come whenever I override the default template for a DataGridColumnHeader it can no longer be resized by the user even though CanUserResizeColumns is set to true for the datagrid? Is there something that I need to add to the template to restore this functionality?

Here's my template xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" Margin="-1,0,0,0"  Background="#f9f9f9" BorderBrush="Gray">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{TemplateBinding  Content}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap"/>                           
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>                        
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the [Thumb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) control to the template. You haven't posted template markup code, but you can check [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jaimer/styling-microsofts-wpf-datagrid) for complete example.

Comment: I posted my template code. I'm curious though, can this be done without doing any code behind? I use this template all over my project, so I'd have multiple copies of the same method.

Comment: +1, but it's just another proof of how lame, needlessly complex and badly thought through WPF is. Having to go to such pains just to reenable resizing column headers. It never ceases to amaze me.

Comment: Please don't post links as answers. Case in point, the 2nd link doesn't provide any information about using thumbs or resizing the column headers anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: [WPF Toolkit DataGrid, Part II – Custom styling](http://blog.smoura.com/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-part-ii-custom-styling/)

You can download sample code here to style a DataGridColumnHeader in XAML.