# WPF DataGrid Column Header Resize with Custom Style

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid (.NET 4) with custom template columns and header styles and would like to be able to adjust the size of the columns :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="Images\monitor.png" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Hostname" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="3"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Columns can still be sorted and re-arranged but not resized - the gripper does not show. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133097/wpf-datagrid-template-removes-ability-to-resize-columns) answer and looked at the Thumb control, however this seems like massive overkill to reproduce functionality already provided. The MSDN blog post references a StaticResource - RowHeaderGripperStyle which they don't provide!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I always do it this way and it works pretty fine:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <!-- here goes some setters -->

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- some stuff, like border etc. -->

                    <ContentPresenter />

                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" Grid.Column="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Width="2" BorderThickness="1"
                        BorderBrush="{Binding VerticalGridLinesBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                        Cursor="SizeWE"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: It certainly doesn't work in a `ListView` / `GridView` (`Thumb` is dead)

Comment: But the question was about DataGrid, not a ListView

Comment: I know, I'm not questioning that, I didn't downvote. It's just a side note left for people who come across your answer searching for a solution for `ListView` (like I was). What they can use is http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2008/05/06/wpf-listviewgridview-minimum-and-maximum-width-for-a-column.aspx

Comment: It is important to name the Thumb: PART_RightHeaderGripper as mentioned in the code example. I did not do this and then it does not work as expected!

Comment: I know it's an old post but it will save some researching for people who are looking to custom resizer on `ListView` just change the name from `PART_RightHeaderGripper` to `PART_HeaderGripper`.

Comment: If someone is wondering how to get the drag handle to the left side, `x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left"` works.

Comment: If you want to make the thumb larger, but don't want to show the borders of the thumb, set `OpacityMask="Transparent"`. Setting `Background="Transparent"` will still show borders.

Comment: Thanks @SOReader.