# WPF Datagrid - aligning cell text with header text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to align the header text with the text of cells beneath it?

My data grid looks like this and the text doesn't line up like I expected.  (Datagrid control is everything inside the orange lines - ignore the text outside that)

[image]

My XAML is like this

```
<DataGrid Margin="0,0,0,5" Height="Auto" Width="auto" Block.TextAlignment="Left"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column"  IsReadOnly="True"   >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Document Category"  Binding="{Binding categpry}"   />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Distinct ID" Binding="{Binding distinctIDCount}"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Occurence (%)"  Binding="{Binding percent, Converter={StaticResource roundPercent} }"  />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Do you want to modify header or row? header style should be possible by DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414725/wpf-datagrid-column-header-resize-with-custom-style

Comment: @AryanFirouzyan  I suppose the row since I don't think the header text would look very good so close to the left edge.

Comment: So you need to have customized DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175546/wpf-custom-datagrid-column-header

Comment: @AryanFirouzyan Does the DataGridTemplateColumn replace my existing DataGridTextColumn?

Comment: @erotavlas  If you go with that approach, then yes you need to replacr your TextColumn

Answer (score 0):

You can have an ElementStyle here.

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

Here I just aligned it horizontally to right, but you can fully customize your `TextBlock` (`DataGrid` is using `TextBlock` to render the cells of this column)