# I have ColumnHeaderStyle for Datagrid and Now i don't want to resize Columns

Tags: wpf

How can I resize datagrid'sColumns?
I have `ColumnHeaderStyle` for `Datagrid` and Now i don't can resize Columns!
Please help me!

i treid this code. but it does not work
CanUserResizeColumns="True"

```
<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <StackPanel >
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="/Images/Photo.png"/>
                        <TextBox  Name="txtCaption" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"  />
                    </DockPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>          

<DataGrid Name="mainGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFEBEBFF"
                  ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}">
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Instead of using ColumnHeaderStyle use "DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle"                                                   
 code: <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

Comment: If u use like that means u can resize

Comment: that is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414725/wpf-datagrid-column-header-resize-with-custom-style

Answer (score 0):

In your case: you are using ColumnHeaderStyle so it restricts from resizing.

By default CanUserResizeColumns is true.

Instead of using ColumnHeaderStyle use below code:

```
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header1"  Width="auto" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{myUserControls:CultureAwareBinding Path=xxxxx}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Comment: I have Image and TextBox in my style

Comment: I will show (in Header) a photo for each column. It works but now I can not anymore resize columns

Comment: Do you have any fixed width for image?

Comment: No. My photo has only Source and Dock

Comment: <DataGridTextColumn HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MyHeaderTemplate}"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MyHeaderTemplate">
 <Grid><!-- i'm too lazy to layout all here :) -->
   <Image Source="xxx.png"/>
 </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

Comment: Try like above one

Comment: thank you for your help
I have found the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414725/wpf-datagrid-column-header-resize-with-custom-style